# I want to get number of leaves available for employees in java

Tags: java

```
CONSTClass otherClass = new CONSTClass();
availableLeave = otherClass.serviceperiod(leaveType);
```

In `CONSTClass`:

```
private int calDaysDiff(){
    String sql = "SELECT `joining` FROM `employee` WHERE `EMP_ID`='"+empId+"'";
    Conn c=new Conn();
    Date dateFromSql=null;

    try {
        Connection conn=c.createConn();
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
           sdate=rs.getString(1);
        }

        dateFromSql = dateFormat.parse(sdate);
        System.out.println(sdate);     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cal.setTime(dateFromSql);
    Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(cal2.getTime());   
    int daysDiff =(int)((cal2.getTimeInMillis()-cal.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*3600*24));
    return daysDiff;
}

public int serviceperiod(String Type){
    int daysDiff = calDaysDiff();
    int deductyear= daysDiff - 365;
    int days = 0;
    String sql = "SELECT numOfChildren FROM employee WHERE EMP_ID = '"+empId+"'";

    String sql2= null;
    Conn c=new Conn();
    int numchildren= Integer.parseInt(sql);

    try {
        Connection conn=c.createConn();
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();
        numchildren = Integer.parseInt(sql);
        System.out.println(sql);  
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(daysDiff >= 365){  
        if(Type == "Casual"){
            sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_1'";
        }
        else if(Type == "Medical"){
            sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_2'";
        }
        else if(Type == "Annual"){
            if(deductyear <=90 && deductyear >0){
              sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_3'";
            }
            else if(deductyear <=181 && deductyear >=90){
              sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_4'";   
            }
            else if (deductyear <=273 && deductyear >=181){
               sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_5'"; 
            }
            else if (deductyear <=366 && deductyear >=273){
               sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_6'"; 
            }
            else{
                sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_7'"; 
            }
        }
        else if(Type == "Maternity"){
            if(numchildren<=2){
                sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_8'";
            }
            else{
                sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_9'";
            }
        }
        else if (Type == "Short_Leave"){
            sql2 = "SELECT `LeaveNo` FROM `leave` WHERE `Leave_Id`= 'LV_10'";
        }
        days = Integer.parseInt(sql2);
        System.out.println(sql2);
     }
     else{
        days = 0;
     }
     return days;
 }
```

What `calDaysDiff()` method does is it calculate difference between employee joining date and today. `public int serviceperiod(String Type)` takes the leave available for the employee.

Once click the drop down item that is relevant to a leave type it should automatically calculate the available number of leaves and display in a text box. I want to know is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: whats the problem you are having

Comment: as a sidenote, you should take a look at the [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(sql);` the statement doesnt make sense to me

Comment: The code is not working it shows some exceptions.java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1439)
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:364)
 at CONSTS.CONSTClass.calDaysDiff(CONSTClass.java:58)
 at CONSTS.CONSTClass.serviceperiod(CONSTClass.java:76)
 at Leave.LeaveManagement.select_LV_TypeActionPerformed(LeaveManagement.java:446)
 at Leave.LeaveManagement.access$000(LeaveManagement.java:22)
 at Leave.LeaveManagement$1.actionPerformed(LeaveManagement.java:143)

Comment: some exceptions? what is the exact exception

Comment: Please add additional details to your question instead of the comments.

Comment: The NPE stack trace at CONSTS.CONSTClass.calDaysDiff(CONSTClass.java:58) is fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
 ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sql);
```

does not give a result. So

```
 while (rs.next()) {
       sdate=rs.getString(1);

    }
```

is not filling sdate. And if you want to parse it 
`dateFromSql = dateFormat.parse(sdate);`
, you get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you check, if the SQL-Statement ist working? For example log into the database and try the query against it to verify that there is content resulting. Perhaps you don't have any entries for the used empId. To be secure at the point of dateFromSql = dateFormat.parse(sdate) you can put a check for null around and if there was not entry found in the database you have to decide what to do instead, e.g. you can put out "no date entry for empId found"